# Is there any XMPP Jingle Implementation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmpp

Is there any XMPP Jingle Implementation in Javascript, I only see libJingle library written in C++.

Comment: What are you planning to use it with, nodejs?

Comment: In long run yes with nodejs, but I would like to know if there are any javaScript library, that can be used with other libraries like YUI or Jquery etc.

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at a few JS libraries mentioned here: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/

Comment: Currently I got started with strobejs, But I don't know if it will support jingle.

Comment: Matt- Are there any jingle implementation on nodejs,

Comment: I would also like to know this.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this post is old, but there is one now: https://github.com/legastero/jingle.js